# Vuejs popover menu: apply CSS transform when right-click happens near bottom of the page

Tags: vue.js

I want to dynamically apply a CSS style to `transform:translateY` a menu context (div) whenever it is clicked near the bottom of the page so that it opens upwards and fits inside the page.

This is the element `FileContectMenu.vue`:

```
 <template>
  <el-popover
    ref="contextMenuPopover"
    placement="top-start"
    trigger="manual"
    v-model="value"
    :visible-arrow="false">
      <ul
        v-for="(folder, index) in items"
        :key="index"
        class="u-list-unstyled">
        <li
          v-for="item in folder"
          :key="item.action">
          <a class="u-block"
            @click.stop="click($event, item)">
            {{ item.label }}
          </a>
        </li>
        <hr class="u-mt2 u-mb2" />
      </ul>
      <ul class="u-list-unstyled">
        <li key="close">
          <a class="u-block"
            @click.stop="close">
            Close
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </el-popover>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'FileContextMenu',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    value: {
      type: Boolean
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleDocumentClick)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleDocumentClick)
  },
  methods: {
    click (event, item) {
      this.$emit('contextmenuclick', item.action, item)
      this.close()
    },
    handleDocumentClick (event) {
      const popover = this.$refs.contextMenuPopover

      if (popover) {
        const popoverElement = popover.$el

        if (popoverElement && popoverElement.contains(event.target)) {
          let clickPosition = event.screenY
          let windowHeight = window.innerHeight
          let distanceTillBottom = windowHeight - clickPosition

          if (distanceTillBottom < 130) {
            console.log('Apply style "transform:translateY(-300px)"')  // <-- Apply the CSS transfor
          }

          return
        } else {
          this.close()
        }
      }
    },
    close () {
      this.$emit('input', false)
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Inside the `if (distanceTillBottom < 130)` I want to apply the CSS transform to the `el-popover` element. Something like: `style = "transform:translateY(-300px)"` but I can't manage to do it.

Any insights on how to go about this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
this.$refs.contextMenuPopover.$refs.popper.style.transform = 'translateY(-250px)'
```

Comment: Hey Djiss, thank you for your help! I'm getting this error when running your code:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined
    at VueComponent.handleDocumentClick (FileContextMenu.vue?ede4:73)`. How could I fix it? I know it's a basic question, but I'm starting with Vue. Thanks :)

Comment: did you try to console log `this.$refs.contextMenuPopover`, from your message it looks like it is not grabbing the element, try maybe to replace it by the element you have declared previously in your method: `popover.style.transform = "translateY(-300px)"`

Comment: Thanks again @djiss! I managed to make it work with `this.$refs.contextMenuPopover.$refs.popper.style.transform = 'translateY(-250px)'`. I don't really understand what's going on in that line, but it works.

Comment: If you feel like editing your answer I'm happy to mark it as valid.